# Shouldn't it be the person writing the check who endorses the check, not the depositor of the check?

Tags: banking, financial-literacy, check

I have to sign the backs of checks other people give me. Why is this necessary? It seems that someone could easily steal the check and write their name instead and deposit it into their own account. Shouldn't the person who's writing the check endorse the check and specify who the check is for?

Answer (score 3):

The person writing the check has already signed and endorsed it. The depositer's signature is not to confirm the check's validity, but to demonstrate that the check was depisited to the correct Fred Smith's account, and permit charges to be brought if, eg, Fred Bonzo Smith tries to steal Fred Gnorph Smith's check.

Comment: Where did you come up with Gnorph?

Comment: Eighth or so Metasyntactic Variable.

Answer (score 2):

A check is simply an order to the bank to pay money to someone. The payor's signature on the front of the check is all that's needed to make that order binding.

If you read the check carefully, you'll see that it says "Pay to the order of ..."; that's the payor's instruction to the bank, and as payee you can make a further order, to pay the money to someone else, in which case you'd **have to** endorse the check to make your order binding. But nobody does that any more; instead, people always just deposit checks into their accounts.

When you deposit a check, the payor's signature is all that's needed to tell the payor's bank that it should pay the money. If your bank insists on a signature as well, that's just to pretend that they're paying attention in case it turns out that you stole the check. In reality, banks don't pay attention to signatures, nor to the name of the payee. I once put the wrong check into an envelope, and the phone company got a check for something over $700 on a bill of less than $50, payable to some completely different company; they deposited it and gave me a credit for the balance; none of the banks in the transition chain questioned it.

Comment: I did the same thing with local utility. Payable to them, but an amount that was way too much. They returned it and I sent right amount. Next month, I found they reversed the automatic late fee. Nice guys there.